# How to use android.media.effect package for applying visual effect to video

Tags: android

In Android API level 14 there was added android.media.effect package. But there is no a lot of documentation about it. I'm interested in applying visual effects to video.

I have sample project from android development site for applying visual effect to image but have no idea how to apply visual effect to video.

Can any one please tell me how to apply visual effect to video.Thanks